# VMware Fusion 2.x not running with 64 Bit Kernel Lion

Tags: macos, vmware

has anyone managed to run fusion 2.x under Mac OS Lion? Since the update it says

**Incompatibility with 64 bit kernel**

This release of VMware Fusion does not work with 64-bit kernel of Mac OS X, you are currently running.
To use VMware Fusion, you must restart your computer using the 32-bit kernel of Mac OS X again.

Any ideas :( ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to VMWare Fusion 3.1 which is compatible with Lion, with limited support from VMWare.

[VMWare's knowledge base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003715) says

> VMware Fusion 3.1.3 was designed for OS X 10.5 (Leopard) and OS X 10.6
>   (Snow Leopard). It is compatible with Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), with the
>   limitations listed below.
>
> If you are running an older version of VMware Fusion, upgrade to
>   VMware Fusion 3.1.3 before upgrading to Lion. Fusion 2.x is
>   incompatible with Lion.

Comment: I would assume if you upgrade the OS all programs will fail unless you read otherwise. (You don't have to upgrade the OS)

Comment: Why should they fail? Just look at the windows world, do you know lots of programs that ran under Vista and will not run in Windows7?

Comment: Because OSs change the APIs that are called and how things work - After each upgrade there are always bugs - maybe not many but some and Sod's Law dictates one bug will be for a program you use.

Answer (score 1):

VMware have said that Fusion 2.0 is incompatible with Lion.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003715

Version 3 on the other hand, does offer Lion support.

Note also that the latest version of freeware Virtual Box is also Lion compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the link :-) … a highlight from the 22nd July 2011 edition, emphasis added by me: "VMware can provide **best effort** support if you choose to upgrade to Lion, but we **cannot guarantee a resolution** for all issues." — based on that line from VMWare you might edit your answer to clarify that VMWare support for virtualisation of Lion is currently limited.